# Does GWK Google Web Toolkit require Java on Client Browsers?

Tags: gwt, browser, client, java

I want to ask is that does GWK Google Web Toolkit require Java on Client Browsers?

Comment: Why would it?  It generates Javascript on the client side, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, GWT (not GWK) uses Java merely as a convenience for developers.  But after compilation, the product is 100% Javascript, so no JRE is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it doesn't, it just compile java into javascript, usually good javascript that can work on multiple browsers.

Comment: I was thinking then how does it RPC with server.

Comment: As every app does, it does RPC via ajax calls, then the RPC handlers on the server ar just enhanced servlets who decode the request parameters and by reflection calls them in appropriate order.

Comment: Maybe a little bit confusing is the fact that for development mode, you need indeed a browser plugin, this is just because the compile process can be quite long and is not practical to wait that long while you're developing but besides that, it converts java code into javascript that do whatever javascript does :)